# Docker Login Error message

Tags: docker

When I try to login to remote Docker registry with command :

```
docker login -e testid@gmail.com -u test -p xyzz
```

password is incorrect. Then it shows this error.

> Error response from daemon: Wrong login/password, please try again

but again I input same command with incorrect password Docker change the error by this new one

> Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/users/:
>   dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

Why Docker change this error message? How can get this error message every time ?

> Error response from daemon: Wrong login/password, please try again...

Answer (score 1):

The second error is implying that you have a broken DNS setup on the docker engine side (if you're not running the client on the same machine as the daemon).

Try using a tool such as nslookup to test resolving index.docker.io a couple of times. If you get the same sort of result, then try investigating your network setup. Otherwise, submit a bug report to the docker issue tracker at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues

Good luck.